# QT Type being defined as an int by an external library?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake

I am working on integrating a project into another project, and am having some build issues with QT.
The issue I am getting is a line being produced in a moc file thats declares QMetaType::Bool.
It says "expected unqualified-id before 'int'", followed by a couple bracket errors down the line caused by that one error.
Based on my research, other people say it is due to xlib.h somewhere else in the project defining Bool as an int.
I have tried the '#undef Bool' line, but it doesnt seem to work. When I place it in the header of the most recent cpp file in the call stack, the error mentioned above goes away, but it also breaks all the objects I have declared in said cpp file, giving me a bunch of undefined reference errors that I know are not true.
So two questions:

1. Why am I getting an error where it takes a different definition of Bool from a different library, despite me calling out the QMetaType:: namespace explicitly?
2. Any ideas of other ways to resolve this issue?

Edit: This is the function block causing the issue in the moc file.

```
#undef QT_MOC_LITERAL

static const uint qt_meta_data_FUNCTIONNAMEREDACTED[] = {

 // content:
       7,       // revision
       0,       // classname
       0,    0, // classinfo
       6,   14, // methods
       0,    0, // properties
       0,    0, // enums/sets
       0,    0, // constructors
       0,       // flags
       0,       // signalCount

 // slots: name, argc, parameters, tag, flags
       1,    0,   44,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,
       3,    1,   45,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,
       5,    1,   48,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,
       6,    0,   51,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,
       7,    1,   52,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,
       9,    1,   55,    2, 0x0a /* Public */,

 // slots: parameters
    QMetaType::Void,
    QMetaType::Void, QMetaType::Int,    4,
    QMetaType::Void, QMetaType::Int,    4,
    QMetaType::Void,
    QMetaType::Void, QMetaType::Bool,    8,
    QMetaType::Void, QMetaType::QString,   10,

       0        // eod
};
```

Comment: Concerning 1.: The problem of `xlib.h` is not the `Bool` but that it is defined as macro (e.g. `#define Bool int`). Preprocessing (the step which replaces macros) is inherited from C and completely namespace agnostic. That's why (expecially such) macros are considered as mostly bad in C++. Unfortunately, C++ was not yet invented when the `xlib.h` was founded. The hint with the `#undef Bool` is correct but you have to insert it  at the right place (before first occurrence of `QMetaType::Bool` and after `#include <xlib.h>`).

Comment: In combination with MOC generated code this might not be that easy. A possible workaround: run MOC once and edit the generated file afterwards. (And prevent that MOC overrides the file in each build.)

Comment: Just for clarification, the error comes up from the line:
"QMetaType::Void, QMetaType::Bool,    8,"
And this is a generated moc_ file, not a file I wrote.

And to Scheff, whose comment just showed up:
The cpp file this moc was generated from, I placed the undef line in here and it did nothing. I tried it in the header for this cpp file, and it broke it via those undefined reference errors I mentioned above.

Comment: If the `#undef Bool` didn't work, it was not in the right place. Are you aware how pre-processing works in general?

Comment: If the `#undef Bool` is somewhere not effective, I would check specifically the c++ file where this error occurred in. (Even if the error pops up in a header, you have to focus on to the c++ file which is compiled.) You can compile this specific file with `-E` and will get a (very long) new source file where every macro replacement was done. To evaluate this is surely very tedious. Another option is a command line arg. (forgot which) which shows the performed `#include`s. Thus, you may become aware what includes what in which order. With this, you should be able to puzzle this out.

Comment: I may have made some mistakes in my includes, which caused the undefined reference errors. I had all the correct directories included in my cmake files, and all the correct headers included, but inside the headers, the cpp and cu files included referenced the original directory structure, not the way that this new CMakeLists is including them. Once I adjusted for the different directory structure, those errors went away.
I guess I made the incorrect assumption that my includes were all in order, and that the #undef line is what was breaking the code when it was actually working in the header.

Comment: @Scheff, even though my issues was partly due to my own dumb mistake, your comment actually did help. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it and mark it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) in C++ is an inheritage from C.

Roughly speaking, it provides text replacements beyond (before) precise syntactical analysis of the compiler. ([cppreference.com – Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases))

Due to this, the preprocessor is `namespace` agnostic which was not a problem in C (where something like namespaces merely doesn't exist) but it can cause strange effects in C++.

While I heard the first time about issues with `xlib.h`, this is a source of common strange issues concerning `windows.h` (which makes extensive usage of macros to switch between ASCII- and Unicode flavors of API functions).

The intermediate result of preprocessing is usually directly fed into the following compiler stages so that unintended replacements don't become visible to the author immediately.

Nevertheless, each C and C++ compiler offers an option for a preprocessor-only run which emits the resulting C or C++ source code. So, in case of strange and hard-to-explain errors like the one of OP it might be worth to visit the preprocessed source file at least of the C++ source where the errors occur.

(Even if an error is reported for a header file, it must be traced back to the source file because `#include`s are subject of the preprocessing as well.)

These preprocessed files might become scaringly large as a lot of standard and/or system headers may be included (indirectly) as well, resulting in thousands of lines for a single C++ source file.

Another option is to enable diagnostic output about the included headers.

For MSVC++, the resp. option is [/showIncludes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files?view=msvc-160). This option is usually disabled by default because even listing the includes only leads often to a long and inconvenient diagnostic output.

---

Once a macro (defined in a directly or indirectly included header) is identified as source of trouble, one can think how to work-around this issue.

There are mainly two options:

1. change the order of `#include`s
2. `#undef` the resp. macros after the concerning `#include` or at least after the last `#include` in this source file.

This has to be done in every concerned C++ source file.

It could be done in a header as well but this is error prone and I wouldn't recommend this. The reason is simple:

Macros might be defined, undefined, again defined and how this is actually performed depends on the exact order, the files are "seen" by the compiler.
For a C++ source file, this is quite clear as it is a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) on its own.
In opposition, a header might be included in various places before or after other headers which is hardly predictable when the header is written itself.